# OozieClient Exception on Concurrent threads

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have a java OozieClient that is being used by multiple threads in a multi-threaded environment on the cluster to run Oozie jobs. I observed 401: Unauthorized exceptions if concurrent threads try to use the same Oozieclient. The error is random. Should each spawned java thread create its own oozie client? Will that not become an overhead? I am using kerberos authentication in our Hadoop cluster with a keytab file

Comment: What do you see in the Oozie server logs?

Comment: I guess these "401" codes mean that you use the REST API with SPNEGO -- did you set the debugging flags `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true` cf. https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/secrets.html

Comment: Most Oozie jobs are passing but some are giving this 401 error. Its not consistent. Is it possible that while one oozie client is using the keytab to autheticate itself with kerberos, another thread using the same client will not get authorized?

Comment: In theory there might be a "race condition" if some process/thread is renewing/recreating the ticket, and another process/thread is accessing the ticket cache at the same time, because for a few milliseconds the cache file may be empty.

Comment: On the other hand I believe that all Hadoop UIs and REST APIs (except WebHDFS) use some sort of "encrypted cookie" as a 1st-level cache of authentication. The 401 could be a glitch in cases when the cookie is stale, so that the server request another SPNEGO, but the client is in the middle of sthg and did not expect to SPNEGO at that point. Or, a "race condition" on the cookie from concurrent clients. That's just a wild guess anyway, you have to debug the thing by yourself :-/